# Couchbase Analytics Java SDK connection creation + Security Roles

Tags: java, couchbase, couchbase-java-api, couchbase-analytics

I am using the Couchbase Java SDK to query a couchbase analytics service. The process is covered in this tutorial: https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/2.7/analytics-using-sdk.html

The Java SDK provides a `Bucket` object as the means of accessing couchbase. However a bucket is a separate entity from the analytics data-set. For example, my bucket is called `data`, and I have an analytics data-set that I want to query called `requests`.

I cannot find a means of connecting to just the `requests` data-set. The SDK will only connect to the `data` bucket. From there I can query the `requests` data-set by writing some N1QL. This work-around means that the user credentials I'm using to run analytics queries must also have access to my main production `data` bucket, which I'd rather prevent.

**Is there a way to connect to simply the analytics data-set using the SDK?**

The code I have currently creating the connection looks like this:

```
public class CouchbaseConfig {

  @Bean
  public Bucket bucket(CouchbaseProperties properties) {
    return cluster().openBucket("data"); // Changing this to the data-set name returns error
  }

  private Cluster cluster() {
    Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create("localhost");
    cluster.authenticate("Administrator", "password");
    return cluster;
  }

}
```

Using the `requests` data-set name in the bucket name results in this error:

```
Failed to instantiate [com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket]: Factory method 'bucket' threw exception; nested exception is com.couchbase.client.java.error.BucketDoesNotExistException: Bucket "requests" does not exist.
```

Using the `data` bucket name, but authentication username / password "analytics-reader" / "password" (with only `Analytics Reader`) roles results in this error:

```
Could not load bucket configuration: FAILURE({"message":"Forbidden. User needs one of the following permissions","permissions":["cluster.bucket[data].settings!read"]})
```

The only work around I have found is to give the `analytics-reader` user 'Application Access' to the data` bucket

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connecting directly to analytics is possible with SDK3 and Couchbase 6.5 . In all the previous versions (SDK 2.7 included), the only way to query analytics is to connect to a bucket first.